# How to interpret categorical variable in logistic regression with contrast coding

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, contrasts

I'm currently having the following regression that I found a bit tricky to explain:

```
# glm(formula = mask_got_20 ~ Sex + Amount + mask_wearing, family = "binomial", 
#    data = clean_data_third)

# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)    1.50966    0.27831   5.424 5.82e-08 ***
# Sex1           0.13040    0.17904   0.728 0.466395    
# Amount1        0.07623    0.17914   0.426 0.670433    
# mask_wearing1  1.02371    0.27780   3.685 0.000229 ***
#  ---
#  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

exp(coef(r5))
# (Intercept)          Sex1       Amount1 mask_wearing1 
#   4.525197      1.139287      1.079214      2.783507
```

In this regression, I would like to explain the last variable -- mask_wearing, which is a categorical variable recording whether my participants are still wearing a facemask. The DV in this regression is whether the masked confederate receives £20 (1 = yes, 0 = no).

Since my main interest is the intercept, I used contrast coding where the intercept represents the mean of group means, and the parameter represents the difference from the intercept.

How should I compare if I would like to interpret the last variable as: "participants who reported they still wear a facemask regularly are about X times more likely to offer £20 to the masked confederate than participants who no longer wear facemasks."

Should I use the difference of intercept estimate +- the estimate of mask_wearing and then exponentiate it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to choose variable coding on arbitrary convenience, then to get any contrast of interest by subtracting predicted log odds (and possibly anti-logging the difference to get an odds ratio).  This readily generalizes to more complex cases where the categorical predictor interacts with a complex function of another predictor such as a spline function to allow nonlinearity.  In the R `rms` package [contrast](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/6.3-0/topics/contrast.rms) function you'd do something like this:

```
f <- lrm(y ~ sex + mask + x, data=d)
contrast(f, list(mask = 'y'), list(mask = 'n'))
```

Since in this model `mask` doesn't interact with anything, it doesn't matter what values are assigned to `sex` and `x`.  `rms` sets them to the mode and median, respectively.